# Ruby On Rails, Where Do Bundler install gems that are fetched with :git=>'/your_name/project_name.git'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, bundler

This is my first question on StackOverflow. Please bear with me if I am doing it wrong.

I am working on a ruby on rails application and had to change the source code of a gem I am using in

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/gemname-4.1.0.
```

This works well and I make a fork of the gem on github, applied the changes I made, pushed, and change my gemfile line from

```
gem 'gemname'
```

to

```
gem 'gemname',:git=>"git@github.com:/name/gemname.git"
```

I run bundle install again and now the changes made are not applied to my application anymore.
When I do bundle show 'gemname' I saw the gem is install in

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/gemname-a0ed76fc98e2
```

I am not an expert on how bundle and github works. If anymore could explain how they work and what I should do to use my own forked version of the gem in my application, it would be very help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing,

```
gem 'gemname',:git => "git@github.com:/myname/gemname.git", :branch => '1.1'
```

and it works fine now.

I think the problem is that I need to specify the branch 1.1 which is my branch, otherwise it uses the master's branch which my changes are not applied.

Answer (score 1):

you could also write:

```
gem 'gemname', 'git://github.com/name/gem_name.git
```

or:

```
gem 'gemname', github: 'name/gem_name'
```

also be sure that you have your changes in master, and restarted your server after bundle